# Deleting a bitbucket HG repository so that the fork remains

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have a repository, from which a fork was created. Fork is being developed, and the parent repository is forgotten, nothing is changed there for years. At some point we've started to clean up old repositories and found this one. So I want the fork, but I don't need the initial repository. If I delete the repository, the fork will also be deleted. I need some way to transfer a fork into a new repository, if possible.
So, how do I delete the repository and keep a fork and all the commit history from the point it was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the original. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
I see that the link was removed, everything else unchanged.